# リストの表示ができません

Tags: python

作成したリストに2をかけた値を計算し表示したく、以下のコードを書いたのですがうまくできません。どうしたらよいでしょうか？

```
numbers = [1, 3, 5, 7]
for n in numbers*2:
    print(n)
```

実行結果

```
1
3
5
7
1
3
5
7
```

Answer (score 1):

解法は下記コードのように複数考えられます。
`numbers*2`は**配列そのものを2倍にする**ので、そこを見直してください。
`numbers = [1, 3, 5, 7]`なので、`numbers*2`は`[1, 3, 5, 7][1, 3, 5, 7]`→`[1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5, 7]`のイメージで計算されます。

※ご質問のように要素ごとに改行しながらprintするよう修正しました。
※末尾の Ex. を実行するにはnumpyパッケージをインストールする必要があります。

```
numbers = [1, 3, 5, 7]

print("1. numbersの個数分インデックスを加算しながらループして配列内の項目それぞれの値を2倍する")
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    print(numbers[i]*2)

print("2. numbersを1つずつ取り出して2倍した値を表示する")
numbers = [1, 3, 5, 7]
for n in numbers:
    print(n*2)

print("3. 内包表記で配列内の全項目に2を掛け、mapで配列要素にprint関数を適用して表示する")
list(map(print, [n*2 for n in numbers]))

print("Ex. numpyを使って2倍したnp.arrayを展開して改行文字区切りで一括printする")
import numpy as np
ar = np.array(numbers)
print(*(ar * 2), sep="\n")
```